# Issue in search when using datatables with row grouping

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable with two level row grouping. If i search anything in the table, it searches the data correctly but removes all grouping or merges all searched data into one group.

I have tried most of things i found on the internet but none of them were useful.

This is my code:

```
drawCallback: function ( settings ) {
    var api = this.api();
    var rows = api.rows( {page:'all'} ).nodes();
    var last = null;
    var sublast = null;

    var grupo;

    var total = null;
    var subtotal = null;
    var a_origen = null;

    var intVal = function ( i ) {
        return typeof i === 'string' ? i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '_')*1 :
            typeof i === 'number' ? i : 0;
    };

    api.column(0, {} ).data().each( function ( ctra, i ) {
        ctra_assoc = ctra.substring(0, 6);
        if (last !== ctra) {
            $(rows).eq( i ).before(
               '<tr class="group" height= "50px"><td colspan="5">'+ctra.toUpperCase()+'</td><td colspan="2" class="'+ctra_assoc+'"></td></tr>'
            );
            total = intVal(api.column(8).data()[i]);
            last = ctra;
        } else {
            total += intVal(api.column(8).data()[i]);

        }
        $("."+ctra_assoc).html(total.toFixed(2));
        a_origen += intVal(api.column(8).data()[i]);

        grupo = api.column(1).data()[i];
        grupo_assoc = grupo.replace(/\s/g, "_");
        if (sublast !== grupo) {
            $(rows).eq( i ).before(
               '<tr class="subgroup" height= "50px"><td colspan="5">'+grupo+'</td><td colspan="2" class="'+ctra_assoc+'_'+grupo_assoc+'"></td></tr>'
            );
            subtotal = intVal(api.column(8).data()[i]);
            sublast = grupo;
        } else {
            subtotal += intVal(api.column(8).data()[i]);
        };
        $("."+ctra_assoc+'_'+grupo_assoc).html(subtotal.toFixed(2));
    } );

    $(".panel-title").html('Listado de operaciones ejecutadas | Total a origen: '+a_origen.toFixed(2)+' €');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mvwf3qwm/3/

I´ve tried with a few cases, for example:

If i search for code 12512 the result is ok.

If i search for code 12411 then i lose the "first level grouping".

If i search for code 22314 then all grouping is lost.

It seems to fail when you ask for rows that are separated from the row named groups.

Is there anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `{page:all}` to `{page: current}`.

Problem here is that when you filter by '22314', `rows` by which you iterate, contain all (16) rows in you example, and groupings are added to the very first row(*which is hidden now, after filtering*) thats why you dont see your groupings.

You need to iterate over filtered rows, that why you should apply `{page: current}`

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mvwf3qwm/4/

Reference docs:

https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier#page
https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Comment: Thank you very much. Your explanation resolves the hidden groups issue but there is another problem, when i filter by '22314' the group to wich belongs changes from 'Grupo II' to 'Grupo I'.

Comment: Obviously you need to apply `{page: current}` in every place when you get `api.column` and reset `sublast = null` when parent group is about to render.


Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/mvwf3qwm/6/

Comment: Perfect. That works like i was looking for. Thanks for your interest!